# Powershell - How to scroll through the output using a keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling

I am using Windows 10 - PowerShell to connect to some VPS over ssh.

## How can I scroll up/down through the screen buffer (I have 6000 height set in Screen Buffer Size) using only keyboard.

I've already tried in Windows 10 - Powershell use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll line by line and it doesn't work on my Windows 10.

[image]

[image]

I know the there is a "more" command for paging through the screen buffer, but some keyboard shortcuts would be much more comfortable. I have <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys on my keyboard (standard TKL keyboard). Buy they simply don't work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> to scroll the output line by line.

They don't work by themselves, to scroll the buffer one page up or down, either.

I was looking for answers here:
[Powershell screen buffer](https://serverfault.com/questions/37545/powershell-screen-buffer)
but I don't understand what: "The scrollback is provided by Windows console itself, not by the shell inside (just like xterm and similar apps in Unix)." means.

I've also tried [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/powershell-not-scrolling/) with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by your link actually works :
[Powershell screen buffer](https://serverfault.com/a/37572/18736).

You may enter this sequence :
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> , <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>.

From now on, and until you press
<kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
the arrow and the paging keys will scroll the screen buffer.

You may also use a key-macro product, such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
to assign this entire sequence to one hotkey, for ease of use.

Comment: When I press Alt+Space simultaneously and then "E" and then "L" nothing works. Should I see something happening while pressing this key sequence? I know that pressing "Alt and Spacebar" brings up the program's window menu. I should be able 2 move, resize, maximize, and shut the window with this one. But on my PowerShell "Alt+Space" does nothing.

Comment: Alt+Space should open the menu in the upper-left corner of the window, E to select the Edit sub-menu, and L the Scroll item. Language differences might require other letters. Try to mouse-open this menu by clicking on the icon.

Comment: When I click right mouse button on the title bar of the PowerShell window, and the menu appears, , pressing "E" to select the Edit sub-menu (It WORKS), and "L" the Scroll item (It WORKS). But "Alt+Space" pressed with PowerShell window active, doesn't open the right click window menu, it's supposed to open. But "Alt+Space" shortcut pressed in Firefox works as it should. In File Explorer window works as well.

Comment: Perhaps Alt+Space does something else on your computer, although it's somewhat abnormal. It's possible to workaround using a simple AutoHotkey script to enter scroll mode with whatever hotkey that you like, if you want.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without any third party programs. I like Windows 10 and it's working fine for me. I just need a way to force this "Alt+Space" keyboard shortcut 2 work as it should - open the system menu - in my PowerShell window.

Comment: Are you perhaps using PowerShell inside Windows Terminal? It won't work there - you need to use PowerShell directly.

Comment: I don't know whether I'm using PowerShell inside Windows Terminal. I don't know what a Windows Terminal is. I'm opening Start Menu, I write "powersh", I see PowerShell blue icon >_ and I click "open as administrator". That's how I open my PowerShell. I think it's not inside Windows Terminal, but I'm not sure. I don't have any tabs within my PowerShell window.

Comment: I do the same as you and run "Windows PowerShell". Very very strange. Does this happen when you boot in Safe mode, to disable all third-party programs?

Comment: No. No Safe Mode here. I have my laptop normally booted with 2 different browsers opened, Messenger app, Signal app, Notepad++ and PowerShell window opened in Administrator mode. I just want to use native Windows 10 functions instead of installing a separate third party programs to do something, I can easily do, using natively supported OS functions.

Comment: But I guess I'll need to accept your answer, because the "Alt+Space" shortcut works on every other window except the PowerShell. And when I open system menu using right mouse click on PowerShell's window's title bar, then the keys "E" to select the Edit sub-menu (It WORKS), and "L" the Scroll item (It WORKS). So basically you answered my question. I'll leave it for a week to hang here, and after this time I'll accept your answer. You solved my problem half-way.

Comment: If you decide on a AutoHotkey script let me know. It's a wonderful tool, I love it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using powershell standalone and not the version where it is tabbed in terminal, you can set your own bindings:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord F4 -ScriptBlock { [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ScrollDisplayUp() }
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+F4 -ScriptBlock { [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ScrollDisplayDown() }
```

To see all current shortcuts, you can enter `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`

The default binds are:

```
Basic editing functions
=======================

Key              Function           Description
---              --------           -----------
Enter            AcceptLine         Accept the input or move to the next line if input is missing a closing token.
Shift+Enter      AddLine            Move the cursor to the next line without attempting to execute the input
Backspace        BackwardDeleteChar Delete the character before the cursor
Ctrl+h           BackwardDeleteChar Delete the character before the cursor
Ctrl+Home        BackwardDeleteLine Delete text from the cursor to the start of the line
Ctrl+Backspace   BackwardKillWord   Move the text from the start of the current or previous word to the cursor to the
                                    kill ring
Ctrl+w           BackwardKillWord   Move the text from the start of the current or previous word to the cursor to the
                                    kill ring
Ctrl+C           Copy               Copy selected region to the system clipboard.  If no region is selected, copy the
                                    whole line
Ctrl+c           CopyOrCancelLine   Either copy selected text to the clipboard, or if no text is selected, cancel
                                    editing the line with CancelLine.
Ctrl+x           Cut                Delete selected region placing deleted text in the system clipboard
Delete           DeleteChar         Delete the character under the cursor
Ctrl+End         ForwardDeleteLine  Delete text from the cursor to the end of the line
Ctrl+Enter       InsertLineAbove    Inserts a new empty line above the current line without attempting to execute the
                                    input
Shift+Ctrl+Enter InsertLineBelow    Inserts a new empty line below the current line without attempting to execute the
                                    input
Alt+d            KillWord           Move the text from the cursor to the end of the current or next word to the kill
                                    ring
Ctrl+Delete      KillWord           Move the text from the cursor to the end of the current or next word to the kill
                                    ring
Ctrl+v           Paste              Paste text from the system clipboard
Shift+Insert     Paste              Paste text from the system clipboard
Ctrl+y           Redo               Redo an undo
Escape           RevertLine         Equivalent to undo all edits (clears the line except lines imported from history)
Ctrl+z           Undo               Undo a previous edit
Alt+.            YankLastArg        Copy the text of the last argument to the input


Cursor movement functions
=========================

Key             Function        Description
---             --------        -----------
LeftArrow       BackwardChar    Move the cursor back one character
Ctrl+LeftArrow  BackwardWord    Move the cursor to the beginning of the current or previous word
Home            BeginningOfLine Move the cursor to the beginning of the line
End             EndOfLine       Move the cursor to the end of the line
RightArrow      ForwardChar     Move the cursor forward one character
Ctrl+]          GotoBrace       Go to matching brace
Ctrl+RightArrow NextWord        Move the cursor forward to the start of the next word


History functions
=================

Key       Function              Description
---       --------              -----------
Alt+F7    ClearHistory          Remove all items from the command line history (not PowerShell history)
Ctrl+s    ForwardSearchHistory  Search history forward interactively
F8        HistorySearchBackward Search for the previous item in the history that starts with the current input - like
                                PreviousHistory if the input is empty
Shift+F8  HistorySearchForward  Search for the next item in the history that starts with the current input - like
                                NextHistory if the input is empty
DownArrow NextHistory           Replace the input with the next item in the history
UpArrow   PreviousHistory       Replace the input with the previous item in the history
Ctrl+r    ReverseSearchHistory  Search history backwards interactively


Completion functions
====================

Key           Function            Description
---           --------            -----------
Ctrl+@        MenuComplete        Complete the input if there is a single completion, otherwise complete the input by
                                  selecting from a menu of possible completions.
Ctrl+Spacebar MenuComplete        Complete the input if there is a single completion, otherwise complete the input by
                                  selecting from a menu of possible completions.
Tab           TabCompleteNext     Complete the input using the next completion
Shift+Tab     TabCompletePrevious Complete the input using the previous completion


Miscellaneous functions
=======================

Key           Function              Description
---           --------              -----------
Ctrl+l        ClearScreen           Clear the screen and redraw the current line at the top of the screen
Alt+0         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+1         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+2         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+3         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+4         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+5         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+6         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+7         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+8         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+9         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
Alt+-         DigitArgument         Start or accumulate a numeric argument to other functions
PageDown      ScrollDisplayDown     Scroll the display down one screen
Ctrl+PageDown ScrollDisplayDownLine Scroll the display down one line
PageUp        ScrollDisplayUp       Scroll the display up one screen
Ctrl+PageUp   ScrollDisplayUpLine   Scroll the display up one line
Ctrl+Alt+?    ShowKeyBindings       Show all key bindings
Alt+?         WhatIsKey             Show the key binding for the next chord entered


Selection functions
===================

Key                   Function            Description
---                   --------            -----------
Ctrl+a                SelectAll           Select the entire line. Moves the cursor to the end of the line
Shift+LeftArrow       SelectBackwardChar  Adjust the current selection to include the previous character
Shift+Home            SelectBackwardsLine Adjust the current selection to include from the cursor to the end of the
                                          line
Shift+Ctrl+LeftArrow  SelectBackwardWord  Adjust the current selection to include the previous word
Shift+RightArrow      SelectForwardChar   Adjust the current selection to include the next character
Shift+End             SelectLine          Adjust the current selection to include from the cursor to the start of the
                                          line
Shift+Ctrl+RightArrow SelectNextWord      Adjust the current selection to include the next word


Search functions
================

Key      Function                Description
---      --------                -----------
F3       CharacterSearch         Read a character and move the cursor to the next occurence of that character
Shift+F3 CharacterSearchBackward Read a character and move the cursor to the previous occurence of that character
```

[See additional information on the Microsoft site.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: And how can I check, what the current ```ScrollDisplayUp()``` and ```ScrollDisplayDown()``` key bindings are??

Comment: @michalroesler `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` will show all ps shortcuts